# How to update the parent activity's listview on child activity return

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two activities: one `NoteListActivity` which inherits from `ListActivity`, and I used `SimpleCursorAdapter` as its adapter where the cursor is obtained as below:

```
    public Cursor getAllNotesCursor() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT _id , title, content FROM " + NOTE_TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

The another activity `NoteEditorActivity` is responsible for creating new note, there is a `save` action there and on click I will add a new note in the SQLite database then call `finish` to the `NoteListActivity`.

The problem is that the `NoteListActivity` didn't get updated with new note, do you know the best practice to achieve this?

One solution I can thought of is starting `NoteEditorActivity` by calling `startActivityForResults` then call cursor `requery` in `onActivityResult`, I don't know whether there is better solution?

Comment: Use Full Link http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*startActivityForResults* is good, but why not try to override onResume() method, with yourAdapter.notifyDataChange()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    ...
    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Of course you have to add yourAdapter on your field class.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing in onCreate method that is affecting UI to draw or show note by fetching from database.

Don't do it in onCreate.

DO IT IN onResume

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
 //fetch here, do other operation, or set layout here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
notifyDataSetChanged Update List View Adopter

http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/
```

Answer (score 0):

try following steps..

1. use `startActivityForResult()` inside NoteListActivity to start NoteEditorActivity.
2. set `RESULT_OK` in save button click event
3. Populate list in `onActivityResult()` of NoteListActivity